# Настройка типов файлов в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php

Стандартная строка:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .txt
```

позволяет обрабатывать файлы .html и .txt как PHP скрипт, это то, что мне и нужно, но проблема в том, что все остальные на сайте файлы .txt будут так-же выдаются как PHP скрипт.

Мне нужно что-бы только **один единственный файл на сервере** (naprimer.txt) обрабатывался как php-файл, а другие .txt - как обычно.

Кто знает, что в .htaccess прописать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Убери своё правило
Сделай [`rewrite rule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), который URL вида naprimer.txt перенаправит на naprimer.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^naprimer\.txt$  naprimer.php
```

Comment: апача под рукой нет, не проверял как это рабоет

Comment: Спасибо! думал решение будет немного другим, но и этот вариант подошел.
Нужно было чтоб и в url-адресе браузеров было site.ru/naprimer.txt

Comment: так и будет работать

Comment: >Нужно было чтоб и в url-адресе браузеров было site.ru/naprimer.txt

На сколько я понимаю это правило означает что запросы к naprimer.txt будут обрабатываться как запросы к naprimer.php (кстати это означает что naprimer.txt  таки-придётся переименовать в naprimer.php).

Comment: Да. И это нормально, общепризнанно, распространённо, применяется мировым сообществом.